# Matrix and Wygwam / Content Elements plugin conflict

Tags: matrix, wygwam, pixelandtonic

I think I have a plugin conflict.
In the CP, I have a channel with the following channel fields:

- Content Elements
- Matrix with just Text
- Matrix with Text and Wygwam

In the last one, when I try to click on the left column (text), everything works fine but then, when I try to edit the other Matrix column (the Wygwam one), nothing happens, it just stays blank. The cursor doesn't even appear.

In the console, I have the following errors:

```
index.php:1SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
http://mywebsite.com/themes/third_party/content_elements/elements/wysiwyg/ckeditor/skins/wygwam2/skin.js?t=B8DJ5M3Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ckeditor.js:23TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'r.init')
```

What can I do to fix this?

EE: 2.4.0
Wygwam: 2.6.3
Content Elements: 1.0.1

**[Updated]**

Wygwam: 2.7
Content Elements: 1.1.2

I updated the Wygwam and Content Elements plugins and now have the following error messages:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
http://mywebsite.com/themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/plugins/flickr/plugin.js?t=D09H5XKFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
[CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "flickr" was not found at "http://mywebsite.com/themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/plugins/flickr/plugin.js?t=D09H5XK".
```

Comment: Well, the first thing I'd recommend is upgrading EE to 2.5.5.  If you test these fields separately, not both included at the same time, do they work?  I suspect that it's calling CKEditor twice, hence the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Flickr extraPlugin were loaded in the Wygwam configuration.
I just created a new configuration removing that element. Plus I deferred the CK Editor initialization.

It seems to be working now.